# What will happen if a user downvotes every question regardless of quality/person?

Tags: discussion

What will happen if a user just keeps downvoting every question he sees, regardless of the quality of content or the user?

This will cause no harm to the user's reputation as downvoting a question doesn't cause any loss in reputation points, but the person who has asked a question will lose reputation points though the quality of the question was good.

Is there a mechanism to detect this behaviour?

Comment: The serial votes will be reverted and he'll probably be warned.

Comment: how this will be considered as serial voting as users will be different?

Comment: Maybe not "serial voting", but abuse. Blindly voting on a large scale like that is just... Silly.

Comment: Well IIRC nothing was done against the people blindly upvoting every question on certain SEs to get Electorate

Comment: @Magisch vote cap? :p

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking what would happen to the user doing the downvoting which Cerbrus has already covered in an answer. But also, those drive by votes may trigger other people to vote based upon whether or not they agree with the vote rather than the quality of the question.

Comment: Just randomly entered here today, and seen this question. Even if I agree that it is not the best question ever, or even nearly, I don't understand why it took so many down-votes? Can someone explain? The guys is just curious :)

Comment: related question on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269082/158100

Comment: @XMight Meta is full of "why are mean people down-voting me", and similar questions. They get tiresome. No one apart from a user and SE employees know *who* voted on what questions, and no one apart from a user knows what the reason was. Unless Vivek can find some evidence that there are people who just downvote everything for no other reason than the button is there, then this question doesn't seem to be particularly useful.

Comment: A canonical question for *guidelines* on voting is *[When should I vote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote)* (cross-site).

Comment: Have you seen `every single question` lately?? Down votes for all would be pretty appropriate

Comment: Are people supposed to downvote a question who’s main topic is downvotes?

Answer (score 7):

If someone is downvoting everything in very rapid succession, and inadvertently hits a series of posts that are all by the same user in their crusade against the site, then that string of votes against that particular user *may or may not* be reverted regardless of the surrounding votes. We don't know and we can't predict when that will happen, but if it does happen, I wouldn't be surprised. But the reversal is done as a precautionary measure against actual targeted voting cases — the system doesn't know for sure if the votes were indeed targeted.

Ultimately we don't know who is voting on what posts, so if there's anyone out there who is indiscriminately downvoting everything they see, including good content, then there's not much that can be done.

Comment: Well that seems that there is no consideration about this in current scenario. And I want to know how to properly ask question on this site as anything I ask is downvoted heavily

Comment: @VivekMishra your last 10 questions have non-negative votes, so.....?

Comment: I am asking only about this site not stack overflow

Comment: @Vivek, then I would suggest you read [Why are people downvoting my question on Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-people-downvoting-my-question-on-meta) on the Overmeta.

Answer (score 4):

There probably is a system to detect that.

If you go around actively downvoting every single question / answer you see, regardless of contents, you will draw attention ***eventually***.
The votes would be reverted, and you'll get the honor of receiving a warning (or worse) from one of our overlords.

Comment: any time criteria defined for this too?

Comment: Nothing a ordinary user could possibly know. Why do you even need to know?

Comment: like if someone downvote about 5 posts daily will this be detected too?

Comment: 5 posts isn't exactly "excessive" or even uncommon.

Comment: then in case of 20?

Comment: Again, why does the exact number matter? Just don't go around blindly downvoting everything.

Comment: I never do that I just want to know if someone did this with me then will I get my reputation back or not

Comment: @VivekMishra - If someone did that to you, then his votes will be invalidated if it is proved to be revenge downvoting.

Comment: @TheLostMind I am not asking about serial downvoting/upvoting I am asking about one user downvoting everything

Comment: So, you're asking about one user serially downvoting everything.

Comment: yes that's what I am asking from start

Comment: @Vivek, I'm not sure anything would happen. I downvote *a lot* of questions nowadays (since our quality dropped blah blah), twenty a day is not exceptional I believe. Nothing happened to me yet.

Comment: I doubt that it is detected, based on [this question and its answers on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269082/158100)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Well, considering twenty is only half of your daily vote allowance, it's hardly exceptional :P

Comment: I have cast over ten times as many downvotes as upvotes. It's easier to see bad content than good. This is not malicious in any way, and downvotes are a **good thing** -- meant to indicate the quality of a post. When I was slightly more active, I regularly used up all my votes just on the morning commute to work looking at the "newest questions" page. (I probably should have paid more attention to the road, but oh well...)

Comment: As long as you don't target particular users, you can vote any way you want, even targetting [the toilet bowl of Stack Overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/week-2-of-the-summer-of-love-researching-comments/#comment_10) (with JavaScript whitelisting, JavaScript needs to be allowed from *disqus.com*, *disquscdn.com* and *cloudflare.com* to see it).

Comment: I don't need to know the algorithm, but where is it stated that we even have a system to detect this?

Answer (score 1):

It's practically impossible to downvote all the questions because of the maximum number of votes any user can cast in a single day.  You are limited to a maximum of 40 downvotes per day on questions.  From the [vote down privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down):

> You can vote 30 times per UTC day. You get an additional 10 votes on questions only.

Those 40 votes are shared between upvotes and downvotes.  Other answer have already address some of the other possibilities if you happen to trigger a serial voting script with your 40 (random?) downvotes.  Seeing as how there are a few thousand questions asked every day, downvoting 40 questions is not a big deal.

Comment: Yeah but, against a single person, that's -80 rep per day.  I can deplete your 5,879 reps in 2.5 months. And you sure as hell didn't earn all that in 2.5 months.

Comment: That's irrelevant because serial voting a user's post is against the rules. And those serial votes will likely be reversed. The question even specifies this voting is not targeting a specific user, so I'm not sure what your trying to point out.